# $\left \| f_n \right \|_{L^p [0,1]}\leq 1$ and $f_{n}(x)\to 0 \Rightarrow f_{n}\rightharpoonup 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Question 3c)

If $\left \| f_{n} \right \|_{L^{p}[0,1]}\leq 1$ and $f_{n}(x)\to 0$ a.e. x then $f_{n}\rightharpoonup 0$

http://www.math.toronto.edu/graduate/pce/ranalysis/real-analysis-sept-2012.pdf

Attempt

We want $\phi_{v}(f_n)\to 0$

Use Egorov's theorem:

$\phi_v (f_n)=\int_{[0,1]}f_n v = \int_E f_n v + \int_{E^c}f_n v$

1. $\lim_n \int_E f_nv \stackrel{\mathrm{uniform}}{=} \int_E \lim_n f_n v = 0$
2. I cannot prove $\int_{E^c} f_n v\to 0$.

Comment: Is "$f_{n}\rightharpoonup 0$" notation for $||f||_p\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: @PVAL It means it converges weakly.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct until now. Take $r>0$ at the beginning.

$v\in L^q$ being given, let $F_n$ a decreasing sequence of measurable sets such as $1_{F_n}\to 0$ (simple convergence). 
Then by monotonic convergence theorem, $\int_{F_n}|v|^q=\int1_{F_n}|v|^q\to0$. 
Take $N$ large enough so that $$\int_{F_N} |v|^{\frac p{p-1}} < r^{\frac p{p-1}}$$
and name $E = F_N^c$

Using Hölder inequality:

$$
\left|\int_{E^c} f_n v\right| \le 1\times r
$$and you are done.

Comment: what gives you $\int_{E^c} |v|^{\frac p{p-1}} < r^{\frac p{p-1}}$?

Comment: so i guess you mean $m(E^{c})<r$ but how does that imply the above?

Comment: This is the choice of $E$. $v$ beeing in $L^q$, general mesure theory results guarantee you such an $E$ exists.

Comment: can you say what result specifically because v has to be arbitrary

Comment: The weak convergence is: $\forall v\in L^q\ \int f_n v \to 0$. So you can choose $E$ depending on $v$!

Comment: I still don't get why that implies the bound $\int_{E^{c}}|v|^{q}<r^{q}$

Comment: @TKM: see my edit.